# Powershell send-mailmessage to read 17k emails from csv & send to 100 users in each email

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PS script to automate email blast to 17k users. Our exchange security baseline is set to only accept 60 requests per minute. Because I'm looping through the email list (CSV) line by line (sleep 1 sec), it took hours for my script to complete. What I'm trying to achieve now is to send the email to 100 users per request. I'm figuring out how to store the emails in an array of 100 & send the mail before going for the next 100. Any suggestion?

```
$recipients = Get-Content "mailinglist.csv"

foreach($rcpt in $recipients)
{
    Write-Host "Attempt sending email to $rcpt ..."  
    Send-MailMessage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable SendError -From $From -to $rcpt -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $Cred -BodyAsHtml ($Body -f $Subject, $Date, $Venue, $Description, $Image)
    $ErrorMessage = $SendError.exception.message
                If($ErrorMessage)
            {
                Write-Host "Failure - $ErrorMessage" -ForegroundColor Red
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
                Send-MailMessage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable SendError -From $From -to $rcpt -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $Cred -BodyAsHtml ($Body -f $Subject, $Date, $Venue, $Description, $Image)
                }
                ElseIf($SendError.exception.message -eq $null)
                {
                    Write-Host "Email has been sent to $rcpt" -ForegroundColor Green
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                    $n++
                }

}

Write-Host "Total sent = $n"
```

Comment: you may want to add a note about why you are not using one of the services designed for this sort of thing. [*grin*] ///// that said, you can  create batches of items from an array by grabbing them by index - sort of a "slice" from the array. `0..99`, then `100..199`, etc ...

Comment: You are reading the CSV file as though it is simply a list of email addresses all on a separate line. Is that the case, then fine, but if it really **IS** a CSV, show the first 3 or 4 lines. A proper CSV has headers and can contain multiple fields. For that use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet. This way, nobody is sure about what is in your `$recipients` array.. Also, I advice you use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to keep the code readabe and maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a traditional `for` loop and access your array elements by index.

```
$recipients = Get-Content "mailinglist.csv"
$To = <SomeValidEmailAddress>
$LastIndex = $recipients.GetUpperBound(0)
for ($i = 0; $i -le $LastIndex; $i+=100) {
    $upperRange = [Math]::Min(($i+99),$LastIndex)
    $Params = @{
       ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
       ErrorVariable = 'SendError'
       Bcc = $recipients[$i..$upperRange]
       To = $To
       From = $From
       Subject = $Subject
       SmtpServer = $SMTPServer
       Port  = $SMTPPort
       Credential $Cred
       Body = $Body -f $Subject, $Date, $Venue, $Description, $Image
       BodyAsHTML = $true
       UseSsl = $true
   }
    "Attempt sending email to $($recipients[$i..$upperRange]) ..."  # You may want to alter this to be more readable
    Send-MailMessage @Params
    # Other code
}
```

**Explanation:**

I've opted to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) here for readability and manageability with the `$Params` hash table. It is entirely optional.

The `-bcc` parameter of [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) supports a string array (`string[]`). Using this over the `-To` parameter will preserve privacy of the recipients. You can then easily send an email to multiple recipients provided you pass it an array. ***However, `-To` is required for `Send-Mailmessage` to work***. It is recommended to make the email address passed into `-To` something that can be spammed or has a way of handling these types of emails. I have set up the `$To` variable for you to provide that email address. If privacy is of no concern whatsoever, `-Bcc` can just be replaced with `-To`.

Since `$recipients` is an array, you can access its elements by index, which supports the range operator `..`. `$recipients[0..99]` would be the first 100 items in the list.

`$LastIndex` stores the last index of the list, which is the value returned by the [Array.GetUpperBound(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.8) method with dimension `0`. Since the array is one-dimensional, `0` is the only dimension.

`$upperRange` is the beginning index (`$i`) plus 99. Should `$upperRange` ever be larger than `$LastIndex`, it will be set to `$LastIndex`. Depending on your PowerShell version, the `$i+99` and `$LastIndex` comparison may not be necessary. Accessing an upperbound range beyond the size of the array, will just return all of the remaining elements of the array without throwing an error. This is likely just for completeness.

Comment: nice! [*grin*] i've a comment, tho - you can directly derive the upper bound of a collection with `.GetUpperBound(0)` the zero is - i think - the axis you want the upper bound for.

Comment: I changed to using that method.

Comment: neato! the logic seems to flow more clearly ... thanks! [*grin*]

Comment: Updated using the bcc parameter instead. Rest easy my friend

Comment: Great! I maybe wrong, but I think you need at least one recipient in the `-To` as well. Usually this is an address that nobody reads.

Comment: This is it! But I'm getting an error, is there a specific format needed for the array?
`Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Bcc'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage`

Comment: @AlexR As commented, the `-To` parameter is required. See [SendMailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6#parameters). Add a _valid_ emailaddress in there of someone that doesn't mind getting spammed, maybe a Public Folder or an email address that gets all incoming mails deleted by a Transport Rule on the server.

Comment: @Theo, I've updated the post with all of the concerns addressed as far as I can tell. I don't know what else to do without more information about the situation or the environment.

Comment: @AlexR Your original code is using `Get-Content` on a CSV file. For this to work in your original code or in mine, that CSV file should not contain any headers and each email address should be listed one per line. If that is not the case, then we need to make a change.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Well done. There is one concern though and that is the part `($Body -f $Subject, $Date, $Venue, $Description, $Image)`. I guess the `$body` variable is some kind of HTML template, that's fine, but it needs to have `-Body` in front. If you would use Splatting, this would become much clearer. I don't want to add this as new answer since you have tackled the logic really well. (+1)

Comment: @Theo I transformed into using splatting.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Beautiful!

Comment: Yes the CSV is actually just a list of emails, single column no header. The original code is working, but it's too slow sending 1 email at a time, took us 4-5 hours to complete 1 email blast. Now I've tested the above solution but I'm getting error. `Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Bcc'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.` I have the -To hardcoded to my email to test this but still getting the same error.

Comment: When I'm sending to multiple recipients, `$To = 'user1@email.com', 'user2@email.com', 'user3@email.com'` this works. Now when I write-host to display the array `user1@email.com user2@email.com user3@email.com ...`, no comma or quote could this be the case?

Comment: You shouldn’t use write-host for that because that stringifies an array. Simply just type $To to see its true value